# Determine if connection is SSL/TLS or not (ssl=prefer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to find out if a MongoDB connection is secured with SSL/TLS when the connection string is "ssl=prefer"?

I need to connect to various MongoDB servers but in case the server does not support SSL/TLS, I would like to write a warning to the user.

Comment: What module are you using to connect? As long as you can get access to the underlying socket (probably unofficially), you can check for certain properties if nothing else.

Comment: I am using the "mongodb" driver. In the debugger, I could not find any reference to SSL/TLS in the db object of the callback argument.